# Extracting n-highest frequencies by class from CountVectorizer

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have created a scipy-sparse matrix on X_train with sklearn CountVectorizer after doing train/test split. I have a two class issue (negative vs. positive).

I want to figure out what are the top 20 highest and lower frequency terms for each class in my matrix. So far, I have figured out how to do it on the matrix as a whole.

```
feature_names = np.array(vect.get_feature_names())

sorted_countvect_index = X_train_vectorized.max(0).toarray()[0].argsort()

values = X_train_vectorized.max(0).toarray()[0]

small_idf = pd.Series(values[sorted_tfidf_index[:20]], index=feature_names[sorted_tfidf_index[:20]]).sort_index()

large_idf = pd.Series(values[sorted_tfidf_index[:-21:-1]], index=feature_names[sorted_tfidf_index[:-21:-1]]).sort_index()
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by class you mean that you have some boolean vector `y_train` which has the shape of `X_train_vectorized` height.

You can retrieve appropriate positive/negative examples by subsetting by this vector:

```
X_train_vectorized_positive = X_train_vectorized[y_train, :]
X_train_vectorized_negative = X_train_vectorized[~y_train, :]
```

And then running the rest of code that you ran on `X_train_vectorized`.

For more info check [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html).

Comment: Thank you, Jakub. It seems to work. Just for my better understanding - when I slice by y_train and ~y_train both has returned matrix of the same shape though my initial understanding was that shapes should be different. Am I overthinking the issue?

Comment: Are you sure that these vectors are boolean? Maybe they are the vectors of labels. If labels are X1, X2 then y_train_bool = y_train == X1 should do the trick

Comment: So, I am correct in thinking that shapes should be different? The vectors are 100% boolean, basically: 0 & 1

Comment: I checked one more time - the difference is in objects. For negative - <363x1774 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
 with 38583 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format> For positive - <363x1774 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
 with 21996 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

Comment: Okay. The thing is that I was slicing by pandas.Series object. Converting it to numpy boolean masking, get job done.